# c++ memory location with array pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *growArray (int* p_values, int cur_size)
{
    int *p_new_values = new int[ cur_size * 2 ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < cur_size; ++i )
    {
        p_new_values[ i ] = p_values[ i ];
    }
    delete p_values;
    return p_new_values;
}
int main ()
{
    int next_element = 0;
    int size = 10;
    int *p_values = new int[ size ];
    int val;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> val;
    while ( val > 0 )
    {
        if ( size == next_element + 1 )
        {
            cout<< "Im in If"<<endl;
            p_values = growArray( p_values, size );
        }
        p_values[ next_element ] = val;
        cout << "Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): ";
        cin >> val;
    }

}
```

This code is allocating memory dynamiclly . I can understand everything in this code, exept one thing. What is the purpose of this if ? No matter how many inputs I give, program will never go in that if.

Comment: `next_element` is never changed inside the loop?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I noticed this too... This code is from a book. I dont think its wrong. But i dont know..

Comment: Consider asking the author of this code. We're not oracles.

Comment: This code is definitely wrong multiple places

Comment: @IisousXristos Throw that book in the bin and get a [better one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Its from this book : CProgramming.Jumping.Into.C.Plus.Plus   in page 150 ...

Comment: If you are a C programmer then problems should be pretty obvious for you. If you are not then it is a wrong book to learn C++ from beginning.

Comment: I am experienced with programming. I could see the problem with the next_element variable , but It is copy pasted from a book .. How can it be wrong ?

Comment: @IisousXristos yes books and compilers have mistakes and bugs, welcome to the real world. Unless this is exercise and author put that errors explicitly for you to fix, then he should mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never increase the value of the variable `next_element` that is initially is equal to 0

```
int next_element = 0;
```

Thus the expression in the if statement is not evaluated to true and the same first element is being overwritten

```
p_values[ next_element ] = val;
```

The program is in whole has a wrong logic. For example the if statement should look like

```
 if ( size == next_element )
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 {
     cout<< "Im in If"<<endl;
     p_values = growArray( p_values, size );
     size *= 2;
     ^^^^^^^^^
 }
```

And this statement should look like

```
p_values[ next_element++ ] = val;
                   ^^^^^
```

And the while loop should look like

```
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
while ( cin >> val && val > 0 )
{
    //...
    cout << "Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): ";
}
```